# Sticky Note use in Ubuntu from Win 7

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, windows-7, stickynotes

I have used **Sticky Note** in **Windows 7** till now. Now I changed **Win 7** to **Ubuntu**.

I had taken backup of all Sticky Notes from **Windows 7** as I found some solution for How to take backup.

I have also googled for use of Sticky Not in Ubuntu and I found solution like:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:umang/indicator-stickynotes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-stickynotes
```

But I want to restore from my backup. Is there any way to use?

Comment: you can also use `xpad` alternative of sticky note.

Comment: I don't even know if you could run Sticky Notes outside of Windows. Isn't it an OS-integrated application?

Answer (score 0):

Install wine and use your windows applications

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y wine1.7
```

After installing wine just double click on installer and install and make shortcut to desktop.

Comment: Hello there, may I ask: 1) Why do you suggest using a PPA to install Wine 1.7?, and 2) Why do you assume that he knows what's the terminal and where do files go?

Comment: The guy has 100+ reputation in this stackexchange site he knows .